# How to copy an entire server into another server?

Tags: scp, transfer, cloning, overwrite

I have two Linux servers, A and B. I want to transfer all the data from server A onto B, but I don't want to overwrite any server configurations on server B. What would be the safest and most optimal way of copying all the data from A onto B without overwriting any important files?

Comment: Just copy the home folders of the users.

Comment: @harrymc It would be very lucky indeed if that was **all the data**.

Comment: @DavidPostill: It would be all **user data**.

Comment: @harrymc I don't see **user** mentioned anywhere in the question.

Comment: You'd have to know WHICH data you need to copy. A good way to figure this out is to start with a list of the applications you are running on each, and then you can proceed to learning where they each store that data.

Comment: @harrymc I'm trying to copy all data in the server, not just user data.

Comment: @music2myear that sounds like a good idea. So I wouldn't be copying every single folder, just the ones that are being utilized/are important?

Comment: That's typically how it's done. Copying all directories WILL cause problems. Copying only the necessary data still has a chance of causing issues (copying configs that refer to an FQDN, for instance) but these chances are much slimmer, and because you know what you're copying you'll also know what is likely to have caused the issues.

Comment: If you wish also to copy application settings this would need to be done one-by-one and examined well. Not every file can be copied as-is.

Comment: It may be too late for this specific case, but wise filesystem layout in the planning phase of server deployment makes this easy later.  For instance, having all user dirs under /home, and having all Samba data (for example) under /data, and all DNS zones under /var/namedb, or what have you.  On the other hand, having data sprinkled all over makes this task much more difficult.  As you migrate the data, look for ways to improve the logic of your filesystem layout, for the benefit of the next person who undertakes what you are trying to do.